# Creating a get function within a class for an owned array

Tags: c++

I have create the following class which contains an owned array of convolvers, and I have tried to create a getter function to access the convovlers within another class:

```
class ImpulseCreator
{
public:

    ImpulseCreator();
    ~ImpulseCreator();

    OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver> getConvolver();


private:
    //convolver
    AudioSampleBuffer impulseBuffer1;
    AudioSampleBuffer impulseBuffer2;
    AudioSampleBuffer finalImpulseBuffer;

    OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver> preConvolvers;
    OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver> convolvers;
};
```

Then in the .cpp file I have the following code:

```
OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver> ImpulseCreator::getConvolver()
{
    return convolvers;
}
```

On the "return convolvers;" line, i am receiving an error which says:

```
Call to deleted constructor of OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the signature of your function to

```
OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver> const& getConvolver() const;
```

so you are returning a *reference* to the array. As written, it will return a copy of the array, which the compiler seems to be telling you that the copy constructor is deleted.

If you need to be able to modify the contents of the array you could also return a non-const reference

```
OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver>& getConvolver();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning by copy, try returning by reference:

```
OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver>& 
ImpulseCreator::getConvolver() {
    return convolvers;
}


OwnedArray<fftconvolver::FFTConvolver> const& 
ImpulseCreator::getConvolver() const {
    return convolvers;
}
```

The compiler is telling you that the `OwnedArray` destructor is declared deleted. Guessing from the name the `OwnedArray` is owned by someone else, thus you're not allowed to destruct its objects in a non friendly context.